# Object Detections SDK/API

Tags: android, ios, object-detection

I have a problem and I need to identify all the instances of a particular object in an image(clould be from a stored image or from camera). I want to do this on windows, ios and android. Which is the best library/sdk or cloud based service that could help me out.

I tried few options like Vuphoria but it doesn't matches same object in one go across bigger image.

Any help will be appreciated